# Why do VoiceOver speaks out the first col of a html table-header?

Tags: html, ios, voiceover

Good evening clever people,

I have a html table with the following structure:

```
<thead>
<tr>
<th>title</th>
<th>title1</th>
<th>title2</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>hello</td>
<td>hello1</td>
<td>hello2</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

When I try VoiceOver on this table in a WebView i become a strange result. If if click on the title2 column VoiceOver speaks out "title" and "title2". I don't know why but it reads out the first col of the header row too.

Can i avoid this?

Thank you & have a nice Day!

Comment: I think you should add scope="col" to your thead>th.